# Round Number inside Angular Expressions didn't work in Angular 10

Tags: angular

I have a decimal digit which displays inside an angular expressions like this

```
<app-widget-card data="Acceleration 1" label={{acceleration_1 | number : '.2-2' }}></app-widget-card>
```

But this expressions isn't correctly. I didn't find any other solutions, how to round the decimal digit to 2.02, 3.03, 4.44
means only display 2 numbers after the point.

Hope someone from you can help me.

Comment: What is the desired output and what's the current output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use simple javascript method [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to limit the number after point.

```js
const num = 2.10222

console.log(num.toFixed(2))
```

In template

```
<app-widget-card [label]="num.toFixed(2)"></app-widget-card>

<span>{{ num.toFixed(2) }}</span>
```